# react-native-camera > takePictureAsync() throws err code E_CAMERA_BAD_VIEWTAG in android device

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

While using takePictureAsync() method of `react-native-camera`, it throws error(android) like

```
{
 "framesToPop": 1,
 "nativeStackAndroid": [],
 "userInfo": null,
 "message": "takePicture failed",
 "code": "E_CAMERA_BAD_VIEWTAG",
 "line": 2189,
 "column": 45,
 "sourceURL": "http://192.168.31.164:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"
}
```

Code:

```
try {
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
        console.log('camera response : -', data);

}
catch (e) {
        console.warn(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2))
}
```

versions:

`"react-native": "0.61.1",
 "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git"`

Comment: Your problem has an open issue on the GIT repository of the library :
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2485

It's seems to be a bug of the library.
You should tracks the issue